# How can I update an issue status in JIRA via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to connect JIRA via Jenkins and updating the JIRA Issue status once my Jenkins Job is triggered and successfully executed or failed . I am looking forward to use Jenkins POST Build Actions. Also before that I am also facing an validating credential issue .

I have tried using JIRA Plugin , but I dont see and JIRA Issue Updater field in my Jenkins Job created .

I expect 
A. To connect and Validate JIRA Plugin 
B. Update my ticket status in JIRA post JOB execution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **Freestyle Job** there is a post action called **JIRA: Update relevant Issue**

[image]

If you are using `Jenkinsfiles` you should look at the documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jira-steps/).